# Simplify an integer expression involving Ceiling and Root[] of third degree polynomial

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I would like to simplify the following expression

```
    Ceiling[ToRadicals[Root[90 - 6 num + 65 #1 + 12 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]]]
```

with `num` an integer greater than or equal to `16`. I tried using `FullSimplify` with the constraints above, but Mathematica couldn't find a simpler formula. The explicit `Root` is very complex (it involves third and sixth roots). However, I know there exist some identities involving the ceiling function (e.g. those [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)).

So, my question is: is there a (possibly simple) way to reduce the above in a form involving Log, Mod, Ceiling, Floor and similar functions (and possibly get rid of roots)? Any idea?

Comment: `with num an integer greater than (not equal to) 6` Ok, I tried: `num = 7;
Ceiling[ToRadicals[Root[90 - 6 num + 65 #1 + 12 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]]]` and Mathematica said `0`  Also tried with `num=8` and got zero?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: num >= 16. I fix

Comment: Ok, just tried `17` and tried `18` and get `1` ? ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/e26kY.png)

Comment: Yes, right for both

Comment: @Piruzzolo What Nasser is trying to say is that, once a numerical value is assigned to `num`, *Mathematica* happily calculates the value of the expression quickly and with no need for `FullSimplify` etc. Are you looking for an explicit function of `num`? That seems difficult to obtain analytically, but easy to calculate on the spot. Perhaps you could expand on why you need this value; there may be other ways around the problem.

Comment: I have to implement the function in C++ and use Mathematica as a tool for simplification and analysis. Of course, the obvious workaround is to get a root-like function as a model for FindFit for a bunch of values taken using Table. My hope was that finding a function involving Mod and related would improve the performance (and of course, I was driven by curiosity about the approach in simplifying such expressions)